# Delay external javascript load by seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ONE external JavaScript file containing jQuery, Cufon, fonts, and the replace functions. I need this file to be loaded twice once on page load and again 3 seconds after page load. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to load it twice?

Comment: Are you able to edit the "external" JavaScript file? You could just wrap the code you want repeated in a function, then call the function twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to load it twice. How about the following?

```
setTimeout(function(){Cufon.refresh();},3000);
```

disclaimer: I know nothing about Cufon and gleaned my knowlege from [here](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/api)

Answer (score 3):

Don't load it twice. Wrap what you have in it into a function, then call the function once when it loads, and once more after three seconds. For example, you might have something like this in your JavaScript file:

```
doSomeProcessing();
doSomeMoreProcessing();
```

Change it like this:

```
function myJavaScriptFile() {
  doSomeProcessing();
  doSomeMoreProcessing();
}
setTimeout(myJavaScriptFile, 3000);
myJavaScriptFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(jQuery.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )),3000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/